# How can i find the parent id's of a particular children whatever we clicked?

Tags: javascript, treeview, parent

I have a category tree. When iam clicking on one category I want to get the parent id's of that category.

So if iam clicking the id=3 . I want result as [8].
Another ex: When i click on id=1. i want result as [3,8]. If aim clicking on id=10, result= [] because there are no parents of that.

```
[
  { 
    id: 8,
    children: [
    { 
      id: 3, 
      children: [
      { 
        id: 1, 
        children: [] 
      }, 
      { 
        id: 6, 
        children: [ 
          { id: 4, children: [] }, 
          { id: 7, children: [] } 
        ]
      }
    ] 
  },
  { 
    id: 10, 
    children: [ 
      { 
        id: 14, 
        children: [
          { id: 13, children: [] }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone plz answer this in javascript? Thank u

Comment: Are you using a tree library?

Comment: No, Im calling the component reucrsively in veujs.